# uninitialized constant ... error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, initialization

I am getting the following error: `uninitialized constant Profile::STRING_LEN_MAX_DB`.

Here is what I have:

**application_helper.rb**

```
def field ( form, field_name, len = TEXT_FIELD_LEN, max_len = STRING_LEN_MAX_DB )
    x = content_tag "label", "#{field_name.humanize}:", :for => field_name
    y = form.text_field field_name, :size => len, :maxlength => max_len { "#{x}  #{y} <br />"}
end
```

**edit view**

```
<% form_for :profileinfo do |fe| %>
<fieldset>
<info><%= @titlu %></info>
<%= error_messages_for 'profileinfo' %>
<div class="fields">
    <%= field fe, "first_name" %>
    <%= field fe, "last_name" %>

    <label for="gender">Sex:</label>
    <%= radio_button :profileinfo, :gender, "Male" %> Male
    <%= radio_button :profileinfo, :gender, "Female" %> Female
    <br />
    <label for="birth_date">Date of birth:</label>
    <%= date_select :profileinfo, :birth_date, :start_year => Profile::YEAR_FT, :end_year => Time.now.year, :include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
    <br />

    <%= field fe, "ocupation" %>
    <%= field fe, "city" %>
    <%= field fe, "country" %>
    <%= field fe, "postal_code", Profile::PSTCOD_LEN %>
    <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "submit" %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**config\environments.rb**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file
# Initialize the rails application
IRC07::Application.initialize! do |config|
STRING_LEN_MAX_DB=255
TEXT_FIELD_LEN=15
end
```

I've restarted the server after making changes in `environment.rb` but I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Move these lines:

```
STRING_LEN_MAX_DB=255
TEXT_FIELD_LEN=15
```

out of the config loop.

So your enviroment.rb looks like:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file
# Initialize the rails application
IRC07::Application.initialize! do |config|
end
STRING_LEN_MAX_DB=255
TEXT_FIELD_LEN=15
```

And if that dosn't work try:
    # Load the rails application
    require File.expand_path('../application', **FILE**)

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file
# Initialize the rails application
IRC07::Application.initialize! do
  STRING_LEN_MAX_DB=255
  TEXT_FIELD_LEN=15
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the code in: app\views\editprofile\edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :profileinfo do |fe| %>
<fieldset>
<info><%= @titlu %></info>
<%= error_messages_for 'profileinfo' %>
<div class="fields">
<%= text_field_for fe, "first_name" %>
<%= text_field_for fe, "last_name" %>
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<%= radio_button :profileinfo, :gender, "Male" %> Male
<%= radio_button :profileinfo, :gender, "Female" %> Female
<br />
<label for="birth_date">Birthdate:</label>
<%= date_select :profileinfo, :birth_date, :start_year => Profile::YEAR_FT, :end_year => Time.now.year, :include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
<%= text_field_for fe, "ocupation" %>
<%= text_field_for fe, "city" %>
<%= text_field_for fe, "country" %>
<%= text_field_for fe, "postal_code", Profile::PSTCOD_LEN %>
<%= submit_tag "Update", :class => "submit" %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

also the function text_field_for in application_helper

```
   def text_field_for(form, field, size=TEXT_FIELD_LEN, maxlength=STRING_LEN_MAX_DB)
    label = content_tag("label", "#{field.humanize}:", :for => field)
    form_field = form.text_field field, :size => size, :maxlength => maxlength
    content_tag("div", "#{label} #{form_field}", :class => "fields")
   end
```

the gender and birthday are ok , but for the text fields i get no text fields, instead i get the html tags with all the params ... like this:

```
    <label for="first_name">First name:</label> <input id="profileinfo_first_name" maxlength="255" name="profileinfo[first_name]" size="15" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="last_name">Last name:</label> <input id="profileinfo_last_name" maxlength="255" name="profileinfo[last_name]" size="15" type="text" value="" />
```